# How can I get overlapping subpatterns that usually consume each other with regex in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

How can I use regex in Python to identify and extract the patterns '1', '2', '12', and '3' from the string '123'?

It's a part of a bigger problem but solving this might give me the bigger solution.

I tried both `findall` and `finditer`, with positive lookahead and negative lookahead and still couldn't extract both "12" and "1", "2".
My code is as follows:

```
import regex as re

# I intentionally put it as list to see what the join method gives.
pattern = [r"1|"] + [r"2|"] + [r"12|"] + [r"3|"]
pattern = "".join(pattern)
pattern = pattern[:len(pattern)-1]
validation_pattern = f"[^{pattern}]"
input = "123$"

matches_fa = re.findall(pattern, input, overlapped=True)
matches_fi = re.finditer(rf"(.*?<=({pattern}))", input, overlapped=True)
validation_fi =  re.finditer(rf"(?<=({validation_pattern}))", 
                             input, overlapped=True)

list_matches_fi = [match.group(1) for match in matches_fi]
list_validation_fi = [match.group(1) for match in validation_fi]

print(pattern)
print(matches_fa)
print(list_matches_fi)
print(list_validation_fi)
print(list_validation_fi == [])
```

I'd appreciate the help!

I usually get `["1", "2", "3"]`.

Comment: Are you just trying to get all permutations of a string? You do not need a regex for this, it does not match several occurrences at the same location.

Comment: Or, you will simply need to test if your regex fully matches any of the permutations.

Comment: I'll have a look at the similar posts thanks.
I want only a part of the permutations (given as keys of a dictionary in the bigger problem I'm trying to solve) but permutations of substrings and not the entire string. I think finding all permutations and taking only those I need might give me what I need.